# Adding new inapp for live app in Dev Console

Tags: android, inappsettings

I have app in alpha stage in google dev console. 
Also I have the list of InApps for this version. 
I want my app to go live and then add two more InApps in update in new version.
So how could I do all this properly? I mean - not to blow up all current inapps and add&test new inapps?